# VOC error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy"

Tags: python

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy"  error occurred  when iam trying to generate .class file for my .py code using VOC .........please help...thnx in advance

(VoCProject) C:\Users\User\Desktop\virtualEnvs\VoCProject\actualProject>python RGBtoGray.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 1, in 
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Answer (score 1):

Try installing NumPy with `pip`:

```
pip install numpy
```

Then you should be able to import without errors.